# C++ lambda expression

Tags: c++, boost, lambda

I am trying to understand lambda expression.

Its going over my head. Need self explanatory examples

Please !

Comment: You could have a look at the msdn documentation for lambda expressions... http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd293608.aspx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are familiar with the current C++ functors (i.e., classes that implement `operator()` so that they can be called like a function, but have internal data-members that can be initialized), then basically lambdas are a nice extension to that language feature by enabling you to create functors as well as initialize them at the point where they are going to be called rather than having to define functor classes.  Lambdas are also quite flexible as they can be closures, allowing you to "capture" the values of any variables in the current scope.

I felt this was a really great resource on the Visual C++ Team Blog that went through a lot of these features:
[Lambdas, auto, and static_assert: C++0x Features in VC10, Part 1](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2008/10/28/lambdas-auto-and-static-assert-c-0x-features-in-vc10-part-1.aspx)

Hope this helps,

Jason

Answer (score 4):

A lambda expression is a mechanism for specifying a function object. The primary use for a lambda is to specify a simple action to be performed by some function. For example:

```
vector<int> v = {50, -10, 20, -30};

std::sort(v.begin(), v.end());  // the default sort
// now v should be { -30, -10, 20, 50 }

// sort by absolute value:
std::sort(v.begin(), v.end(), [](int a, int b) { return abs(a)<abs(b); });
// now v should be { -10, 20, -30, 50 }
```

The argument `[&](int a, int b) { return abs(a)<abs(b); }` is a "lambda" (or "lambda function" or "lambda expression"), which specifies an operation that given two integer arguments a and b returns the result of comparing their absolute values.

The [&] is a "capture list" specifying that local names used will be passed by reference. We could have said that we wanted to "capture" only v, we could have said so: [&v]. Had we wanted to pass v by value, we could have said so: [=v]. Capture nothing is [], capture all by references is [&], and capture all by value is [=].

http://www2.research.att.com/~bs/C++0xFAQ.html#lambda

Answer (score 3):

A lambda expression (also known as a lambda function) is nameless function defined at the place of call.

For examples, visit [Examples on Lambda Expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd293599.aspx)

Better places to learn :

- [Lambda Expression in C++](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd293608.aspx)
- [Lambda Expression Syntax](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd293603.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

Also another example if you'd like :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    // Initialization C++0x-style
    vector<int> voo = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };

    // Lambda is here
    auto print = [&](int& i) { cout << i << endl; } ;

    // Check that out, no loop !
    for_each(voo.begin(), voo.end(), print);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Lambda is simple. Remember generic syntax 1st

```
[ capture list ] (parameters) -> return-type  
{   
    method definition
}
```

Usually, return-type of a Lambda function is evaluated by the compiler itself and we don’t need to specify that explicitly i.e. -> return-type.

Rest is C++.

For example

1. **Capturing objects**

   - [ ] ( ) { }   no captures
   - [=] ( ) { }   captures everything by copy(not recommendded)
   - [&] ( ) { }   captures everything by reference(not recommendded)
   - [x] ( ) { }   captures x by copy
   - [&x] ( ) { }  captures x by reference
   - [&, x] ( ) { }    captures x by copy, everything else by reference
     [=, &x] ( ) { } captures x by reference, everything else by copy
2. **Capturing this pointer**

```
class Example
{
public:
    Example() : m_var(10) {}
    void func()
    {
        [=]() { std::cout << m_var << std::endl; }();
    }
private:
    int m_var;
};
int main()
{
    Example e;
    e.func();
}
```

`this` pointer can also be captured using [this], [=] or [&]. In any of these cases, class data members(including private) can be accessed as you do in normal method.

3. **Lambda as parameter**

```
template <typename Functor>
void f(Functor functor)
{
    std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl;
}
/* Or alternatively you can use this
void f(std::function<int(int)> functor)
{
    std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl;
} 
*/
int g() { static int i = 0; return i++; }
int main()
{
    auto lambda_func = [i = 0]() mutable { return i++; };
    f(lambda_func); // Pass lambda
    f(g);           // Pass function
}
```

Output:

```
Function Type : void f(Functor) [with Functor = main()::<lambda(int)>]
Function Type : void f(Functor) [with Functor = int (*)(int)]
```

Source: [Learn Lambda function in C++ with example](http://www.vishalchovatiya.com/learn-lambda-function-in-cpp-with-example/)

Comment: Based on the domain/URL of your link(s) being the same as, or containing, your user name, you appear to have linked to your own site/a site you're affiliated with. If you do, you *must disclose that it's your site*. If you don't disclose affiliation, it's considered spam. See: [**What signifies "Good" self promotion?**](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/182212) and [the help center on self-promotion](/help/promotion). Disclosure must be explicit, but doesn't need to be formal. When it's your own *personal* content, it can just be something like "on my site…", "on my blog…", etc.

Comment: It's also a good idea to make it clear that you've actually copied the content from your own site (e.g. "copied from my site: [link]"). SE has [requirements for referencing](/help/referencing) content written by others. Material that is copied which doesn't meet those requirements is commonly deleted as plagiarism. Thus, it's important to make it clear that what you've copied is your own content, which means the referencing requirements don't apply.